# What is significance of khan academy /api/v1/exercises/[exercise-slug] user: http://nouserid.khanacademy.org/pre-phantom-user-2

Tags: khan-academy

So I have a script that interacts with [Khan Academy's api](https://github.com/Khan/khan-api/). Essentially, I use the /api/v1/user/exercises/ call to fetch data on student progress.

Well, until recently when I used a student email that has not yet set me up as a coach the returned data would be for my own khan academy account. So I had a condition setup to test if user == me, and if so to append the user email to an error list and continue to loop through the students.

Now I am seeing the phantom-user-2 as the user, and I don't know if I should conclude that it is actually the student's data or just phantom data as the user value suggests.

Since I use this data to populate a student gradebook, I am concerned about the possibility that a student who does have me as a coach could somehow have a similar value in the user field, so I am hesitant to set up a similar condition to append these to the error list.

I suppose I could test it out and see how it plays out, but if someone in the know could let me know under what conditions the phantom-user-2 appears in the user field it would help set my mind at ease and I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a vendor support question about a specific account, and is not programming related as defined in the [help]. (It mentions an API, but is not about *using* that API, but about issues with an account created. It is individual account support, not general use information related to programming.)

Comment: @Ken, I disagree. The issue is not about a specific account, but about querying any account. He uses the API to get exercise data for potentially any user. The return values when the user does not yet have him as a coach changed and he wants to know the correct interpretation of the return values in order to determine if they are valid user data or an indication of an error. I am busy writing an application that uses Khan API and would definitely be interested to know how such responses must be interpreted. The documentation for the API is not very complete.